# Image contest submission

Tags: support

How does one submit an image to the weekly photo contest? Is there an upload button to click? or do you submit a question containing the image? (that would not make sense to me).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [contest page](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and scroll right down to the bottom and add your photo as an "answer" to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get an option to add an answer. The contest instruction blurb stops and then the next section states 453 answers. The normal box to edit and post the answer is not there at all. Odd.

Comment: @Joe90 Can you edit your question to include an image of what you see at the bottom of the page? It looks like this for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftND9.png That grey button the arrow is pointing at should be what you're looking for. If you don't see it, let me know.

Comment: @Joe90 Sorry, I meant to look at your rep.  The page says somewhere that you need a minimum reputation of 10 pts to be able to post an answer, and you're at 6.  A couple of upvotes and you'll be there, or you can get a few points by filling in your profile info.

Comment: You have 11 on the main Photo site now. Once meta catches up you should be able to post an answer

Comment: @MikeW That was *probably* the problem, good catch. So, the interesting thing is that protecting questions on meta doesn't actually do the same thing as on main. There's no "local rep" on meta, so the 100 point association bonus will get past the protected check the way it wouldn't on main. :) We currently have a bug that causes the usual "protected" banner to not appear. Hopefully we'll have it fixed soon, so this won't be a problem. MSE question about it is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322971/protection-banner-missing-when-i-dont-have-enough-rep-to-answer-closed-and-loc

Comment: Bug Cat noted is fixed now