# Can I ask for a photo rating on the main site?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, critiques

I [submitted something](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7060/11924) for the old Photo of the Week competition. However, it probably won't get viewed.

Can I post a question on the main site asking for a rating of my photo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't do "ratings" here. But if you'd like to receive feedback and critique about a photo, we do that.

It all comes down to how well the question was asked. "Hey guys, what do you think of this photo?" is a very poor question, and won't get favorable responses. However, if you tell us specific areas that you'd like to improve (composition, "mood", lighting, staging and placement, a particular effect, etc.), or maybe what you were trying to achieve, that would be a great question. I'd certainly like to see that question on the main site.

Also, **great questions have good titles**. If 100 people post questions with the title, "Please review my photo", how are we able to distinguish them if we're searching for them? I appreciate it's difficult to come up with a single sentence title for what is possibly an open-ended question, but perhaps something like, "How can I improve this shot of water from a garden hose?" It's specific to the subject.

Thanks for asking here on Meta. I hope you do ask for critique of your photo over on main. =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will be asking it on the site. If I am correct, the question title should be something like “How can I improve the contrast on this photo?”, right?

Comment: That's an OK title, but is still _slightly_ frustrating because it is entirely indistinguishable from existing/future questions asking the same general concept. Better to be specific. On the other hand, don't fret too much about it. We've had questions with worse titles, and if somebody thinks of something better, they can just edit the title anyways. What you suggest is fine enough.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll go with something slightly adjusted.