# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 26, '11 (HOLIDAY THEME!)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 26 December** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Dec 25th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

### **THEME: CHRISTMAS and the HOLIDAYS**

**This week we are introducing PotW themes!** For the next two weeks, all submissions must conform to the `Christmas and Holidays 2011` theme. Anything related to the holidays, including Thanksgiving, and continuing up through the New Year, is acceptable. Shots of Christmas Tree Ornaments, Christmas decorations, Hanukkah, super-tasty holiday dishes and treats, light displays, etc. etc. all qualify. If you wish to submit something for a non-western holiday, feel free to do so, however please provide some information explaining the holiday and if possible, a link to Wikipedia or something similar. Additionally, please refrain from submitting photos that "sorta-kinda might qualify", such as late fall scenery, or simple photos of snow covered landscapes. Make sure there is something key and central to the shot, in the frame, that makes it a HOLIDAY shot! :)

As a theme rule, anything that does not qualify and is not removed on request will be deleted before the end of the contest, to keep things on-theme.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/weekly-featured-image-dec-19-11-holiday-theme)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Everyone who submitted last week, please feel free to submit the same content again. I know the theme was sprung on everyone a little too quick, so hopefully this week will be a bit fair and properly competitive.

Comment: Sooo... is this week's winner ever going to be posted?

Comment: @Martha I'm afraid all the mods seem to be absent...

Comment: Apologies, I was away from internet access. I figured one of the other mods would have taken care of this by now. I guess we can extend the next contest and let Grum's photo stay on the header for 10 days.

Answer (score 20):

## Express Delivery

[image]

### [Large](http://www.mattgrum.com/photo_se/express_delivery_large.jpg)

just messing around with a macro lens (Canon EF 100mm f/2.8 + 30D)

Comment: Great shot! Love the rich color and thin DOF.

Answer (score 10):

**Christmas is Over**

[image: Christmas is over]

Didn't come out quite like I hoped..but I ran out of bulbs to break.  They're in mid air, but its hard to tell*.  This picture will be put up the day *after* Christmas, so I thought something like this might be good.

<sub>*Needed the camera at a lower angle.</sub>

Comment: what are those red pieces BTW?

Comment: @Anisha - This http://www.homedecorators.com/images/items/medium/02500110.jpg

Comment: Why did you break them? Is it is custom?

Comment: @Anisha - nope, not custom.  They're a common symbol of a chrismas tree - the picture was just symbolic of christmas ending.

Comment: Hey, You could have added a broken Christmas tree there too, just to add to the effects. :) :)

Comment: I really, really want to downvote you for perpetuating the myth that Christmas is over at 12:01 a.m. on the 26th. (Hint: the twelve days of Christmas come ***after*** Christmas.)

Comment: I know it's not about commentary, but I think this wuold have been more successful with a less-busy background.

Comment: @mattdm - I absolutely agree.  This was my very last bulb and the first time i got shot that I could really evaluate it on.  Doing it again would have been a lower angle, a solid color background, and a few milliseconds earlier.

Comment: @Martha: Christmas is a made up event and therefore can begin/end whenever you feel like it.

Comment: @Poldie: I'm sorry you feel that way.

Answer (score 4):

**Starting early...**

[image]

She put Mommy's stocking on her head and then made a bee line for the tree...

[enbiggen at Flickr here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reknight/6561584785/in/photostream)

Answer (score 4):

## Shiny holidays

[image: Shiny holidays]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-12-08)

A piece of tinsel shot through a macro lens.

Answer (score 3):

Ornamental

[image]

We need more [entries](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/6547501303/) folks!

Comment: Love that ornament. Is it clear with a gold crust?

Comment: Yes, translucent, with a (probably spray-on?) crust.

Answer (score 2):

**Devious**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Bookeh and a red ornament]

Please visit the full sized image at http://www.flickr.com/photos/mervins_photos/5330037436/sizes/l/in/photostream/