# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 9, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 9 January** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Jan 8th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/weekly-featured-image-dec-26-11-holiday-theme)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: The mod's seem to have disappeared to put up the last week's winner.  I've created the next contest and we'll skip a week apparently.  Matt's winning photo that should have gone up on the 26th will go up as soon as a mod can.  Assuming that's before next monday, the 2nd, then the dates here stand...if not, we'll have to rearrange further.  Either way, submit here for the *next* contest.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I was away in the mountains for longer than I expected, and I figured another mod would have taken care of this by now.

Comment: @jrista - yup, I knew you were away.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: Should we ditch the title aspect of the rules?

Answer (score 22):

### Tractricious

[image: Tractricious by David Pollitt]

Larger on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dpollitt/2292497213/).

Comment: Very cool effect.

Answer (score 21):

**#### Reflection**

[image: Reflection]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6009904378/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Refreshing! :))

Comment: I like the dark bottom edge. It balances the light sky nicely.

Comment: Thank you for noticing :)

Answer (score 17):

**Shy**

[image]

Comment: Title?  (rules.)

Comment: Nvm, we've decided to remove the title requirement from the rules.

Comment: Added one anyway :)

Comment: Love the title:)

Comment: Love the photo:)

Comment: Decided to title it after all - had called it Untitled as a laugh :)

Comment: Love the colours!

Comment: Love all of it. (Including the post history. ;))

Answer (score 15):

**Winged Devil**

[image: Belgian F-16]

I don't normally enter this but since my excuse that the image size is an odd one has disappeared I thought I should enter something.

This is the Belgian F-16 displaying at Duxford during the 2011 display season.

Comment: Title?  (rules.)

Comment: Nvm, we've decided to remove the title requirement from the rules.

Comment: Ooops, very sorry!

Answer (score 15):

### Stormy Weather

[image: Stormy Weather]

This is a long exposure shot from Brighton Pier in Sussex, England taken on New Years Eve.. It was extremely windy and the sea was kicking up all over the place.

You can see the fullsize image [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6612408541/).

Comment: Is your title a (Freudian) typo, or was it intended?

Comment: It's a typo (which I'll fix)!

Comment: Almost looks like infrared, I like it

Comment: Hope you submit this one again, lovely shot!

Answer (score 8):

## Just keep on hanging

[image]

100mm f/8

Answer (score 7):

### Watch out!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Part of the project for my photography class.

Comment: Just curious, what was the project?

Comment: What's in the pan?

Comment: @rfusca we had to set up a studio at home for some still life photos.

Comment: @anisha hot peppers

Comment: Minus the smoke, that would make a good shot for a kitchen wall canvas.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Winter sunrise**, a new year , new day

Answer (score 4):

[image]
Snow Lake from a vantage point.

[Full size link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mervins_photos/6225543586/sizes/l/in/photostream/)

Comment: Your dimensions are off... The image should be 210px high and no more than 375px wide.

Comment: Well I could modify the image to have those dimensions but then i'll be compressing the image and reducing the quality

Comment: Those dimensions are a part of the requirements of the contest, see the posting rules above.

Comment: Sorry about that,I'll post another pic with those specifications

Comment: I think you could crop some of the sky...

Comment: Note that the new picture is entirely different from the original.

Comment: Title?  (rules.)

Comment: Nvm, we've decided to remove the title requirement from the rules.

Answer (score 4):

[Gary The Grasshopper](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nickbedford/6452045683)

[image: Gary The Grasshopper]

Answer (score 4):

Crystal Forest

[image: Crystal Forest]

[Link to high resolution uncropped version](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/dave.faller/images/cam_0037.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Bird on a Stick**

[image]