# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 16, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 16 January** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Jan 15th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/weekly-featured-image-jan-9-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

**Winter sunrise!** a New year , a new morning, new hopes

Comment: Lovely shot. Great mood.

Comment: Its from Punjab ,India !

Comment: Wow! Truly fantastic! Absolutely love the atmosphere...serene.

Comment: feels peaceful watching at it

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Sunflower waiting to open.

Comment: Looks beautiful. :)

Comment: did you edit it somewhat or it is straight from the camera?

Comment: I boosted the saturation and contrast quite a bit.  It was shot with a macro lens, and was very sharp, but color was a little flat.

Comment: Color is no longer flat :)

Comment: No, it's not lol.

Answer (score 12):

## Buffalo

[image: Buffalo in yellow-orange light]

I was shooting movies, glanced over my shoulder and ran to get my camera. This pre-sunset light lasted just a few seconds.  [Larger version](https://plus.google.com/photos/111471664614886058938/albums/5694235458707286625/5694245237589934114).

Comment: This is a pretty cool shot.

Answer (score 10):

USS Constitution, Boston MA

[image: USS Constitution]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/6474768765/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: The halo effect around the rope disturbs me. Is that an artefact from the HDR process?

Comment: yeah. I think so. I tried correcting it, but failed.

Comment: It actually looks a bit 3D. When controlled, the halo effect between linear features can actually add an interesting perspective. Similar accidental HDR effect was featured in one of the recent photo magazines. (don't know which one but i will try to find out)

Comment: I like the halo effect - it makes it seem like we're looking at a model/miniature, rather than a photo.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Bigger version is here: http://1x.com/forum/photo-critique/30722

Comment: Good to see this one again :)

Comment: @jaxxon Thanks, but this is not the one which I submitted previously. In this one the girl has her face turned towards the viewers, and in the previous one she was looking at the tap. :):)

Comment: Ah.. Just a very familiar scene. I remember thinking about whether or not I like that pipe on the right. :)

Answer (score 9):

### Stairway To Seven

[image: Stairway To Seven]

This was taken in the Grand Hotel, Brighton, England on New Year Eve. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6620332189/).

Answer (score 5):

## Light at the end of the tunnel

[image: Light at the end of the tunnel]

Shot at a park in the morning light.

F number       : 5

Exposure time  : 1/125

[Larger version on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6664979821/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: I don't like the format, I Think that 16:9 or portrait format is better for this picture... ;)

Comment: suggestion taken :)

Answer (score 2):

### Gloomy December

[image: Gloomy December]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/4248607)

Answer (score 2):

Two stones and a lake

[image]

larger version here:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/smilesnigam/6589013735/in/photostream/

Comment: I count at least 3, possibly 4 stones...

Comment: haha i know there are more than 2, i just liked the title.

Comment: Also, why the letterboxing? You have lots more width to work with.

Answer (score 1):

**Tall Lonely Grass!**

[image: Tall Lonely Grass]

Shot macro silhouette against the sun set,,

Answer (score 0):

### Buenos Aires

[image: Buenos Aires]

larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/54387391@N03/6694359633/in/photostream)

Comment: You need to read the rules re: image height.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Martha!