# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 23, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 23 January** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Jan 22th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/weekly-featured-image-jan-16-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Looks like we have a theme after all - birds

Comment: Some really good shots this week.

Comment: what is the photo that has received more votes?... in 2011

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Nemo

[image]

Clown fish in an aquarium. Contrary to popular belief, they really aren't that funny.

[Original at Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/3375357341/).

Comment: With fronds like these, who needs anemones?

Comment: Ah, 50 1.4. I like this a lot! Thank you for submitting it. I wish I had some fish like this to shoot!

Comment: +1 I really like this photo. I keep scrolling up and down this page and always pause on this.  Love the lens too.

Comment: I really love that blue, the colours overall are great, but that blue is just awesome.

Comment: Looking forward to having this at the top of the site :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who voted!

Answer (score 23):

### Herd of Shells

[image]

This photo was taken with 49mm of Fotodiox extension tube on a Canon 70-200mm. Each shell is probably around 1-2 cm and it was on a support beam in the ocean. I was standing in waist deep water beeing knocked around by small waves. That plus the extension tube made this shot very tough.

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/4262483)

<sub>*Secret: This is actually a portrait picture with the shells on the side of post but I like this a lot better.*</sub>

Comment: this is superb! :D

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty happy with this one. :)

Comment: I upvoted though I have an entry this week =) lol

Comment: lol. Thank you. I've up'd most this week. I like a lot of them. (including yours)

Comment: Excellent capture..

Comment: Beautiful :) deserves an upvote

Comment: Lovely shot and angle!

Answer (score 20):

### Sleeping Apple Trees

[image: Apple Trees]
[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/4406154)

Comment: The light and the angle make this one seem vaguely nightmarish to me. Not that that's a bad thing in a photograph.

Comment: Thanks @mattdm. I take it as a compliment. That was sort of the intention. This was also the mood of the day; snow storm was rolling in and every now and then the sun rays would pierce the clouds.

Comment: I love the mood that this photo creates.

Answer (score 14):

[image: bald eagle in flight]

Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDe7T.jpg

Comment: Great shot getting his/her beak open like that.

Comment: excellent shot..

Comment: Thanks for the compliments!

Answer (score 13):

**Seagull Family**

[image: Seagull Family]

Don't forget to check the larger version at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/6705328223/in/photostream/lightbox/).

Comment: nice picture...

Comment: Is this from your trip (http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18939/what-things-should-i-keep-in-mind-while-shooting-birds/)? How did it go?

Comment: @drewbenn Yes, it was from the trip. It went superb! I have managed a few keepers and some killers! You can check my flickr stream for a few more birds from the trip, and I'll continue uploading more ;)

Answer (score 11):

### Illuminated St Paul's

[image: St Pauls]

This is a long exposure shot of St Paul's in London. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6478624043/).

Comment: Good one, were you on a boat or the other side of the pavement?

Comment: The pavement on the other side.

Answer (score 10):

## Tiny Yellow Flower

[image: Tiny Yellow Flower]

Shot with a reverse 50mm with a canon EOS 1000D at 1/320 s

Full size on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6707573177/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Excellent colours

Comment: Thank you @VianEsterhuizen

Answer (score 10):

## Frozen horse

[image: Frozen horse]

Lens: 58mm f/2 @ f/4

Lighting: flash + umbrella from right, flash + CTB gel from back left

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-02-15)

Comment: All that's missing is the rainbow and unicorn horn. :)

Comment: This does not look like a real picture. Amazing work!

Comment: Oh, the picture is real, but the horse is a key chain and the fog comes from a fog machine.

Answer (score 6):

White fronted terns.

[image: White Fronted Tern]

Come on, I said I was sorry!  I got you a fish!

http://flic.kr/p/8KD9Mp

Comment: Looks good. Is there larger version available?

Comment: I don't see it on my flickr. Will try to upload one soon and post a link.

Comment: I like the text you added fits in perfectly with the situation :) also nice shot

Comment: I could watch these guys for hours, they were squawking at each other, very sociable birds.

Comment: Friend in the back feeling super awkward to be in the situation.

Comment: Found it, was on flickr after all.

Comment: What lens was this with? The focus is really pleasing but it does seem to have a bit of CA.

Comment: It was the non-VR 70-300mm.  Not a terrific lens - this was one of the few times I used it.

Answer (score 4):

Wooden Pipe

[image: Wooden Pipe]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/billyoneal/6632663451/in/set-72157628709333723)

Was going for somthing that would show texture...

Answer (score 2):

Swan in Boston public garden

[image: Swan in Boston public garden]

Larger version - [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/6394231119/in/photostream/)