# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 30, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 30 January** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Jan 29th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/weekly-featured-image-jan-23-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Arch**

[image]

Stairway on a water tank.  Liked the way the shadows fell on the curved walls.

Comment: Awesome composition!

Comment: Awesome contrast

Comment: Loving this one. Glad to see it's pushing the top :)

Answer (score 16):

### Herd of Shells

[image]

This photo was taken with 49mm of Fotodiox extension tube on a Canon 70-200mm. Each shell is probably around 1-2 cm and it was on a support beam in the ocean. I was standing in waist deep water beeing knocked around by small waves. That plus the extension tube made this shot very tough.

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/4262483)

<sub>*Secret: This is actually a portrait picture with the shells on the side of post but I like this a lot better.*</sub>

Comment: I still find this shot awesome +1

Comment: Ditto. Love this shot, particularly the color contrast...excellent.

Comment: Thanks guys :) .

Comment: +1. Keep on posting it til it doesn't win. ;)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Evening star]

Evening star (Twilight)

An illusory capture , with sky ( Venus ) as the backdrop, lining the mountain which is at a distance , The Tree is very close to the camera

Comment: Glad you resubmitted this, this week!

Comment: @dpollitt: Ya was featured last week ,new to this site so had to delete it after reading rules :)..Thanks

Answer (score 13):

## The Sun

[image: Finally, The Sun!]

Larger image (different crop) [here](http://500px.com/photo/4550005).

Answer (score 9):

## Simple toys for simple games

[image: Simple toys for simple games]

Lens: 58mm f/2 @ f/5.6

Lighting: handheld flash with grid, shot thrice from camera right

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-02-24)

Comment: What exactly is this all about?

Comment: [Rock, paper, scissors!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors)

Answer (score 8):

"The Wicked Witch"

[image: The Wicked Witch]

This is a synchronized skating team preparing to skate to their program "The Wicked Witch".

Nikon D90, Sigma 70-200mm at 112mm, F2.8, ISO 1100, 1/400s.

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/6748945983/in/photostream/lightbox).  Colour version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/6748956125/in/photostream/lightbox).

There's more drama in the larger version, and more detail in the lace and frills on the dresses.

Answer (score 1):

**"Lovely Colors"** 
Fujifilm S3400. Super Macro.

[image]

Comment: Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide, this does not fit that requirement.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sulphur-crested Cockatoo]

**Suplhur-crested Cockatoo** — shot with Canon EOS 5D Mark II + Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L II USM IS.