# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 6, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 6 February** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Feb 5th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/weekly-featured-image-jan-30-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Every week there are many submissions with wrong image dimensions. Maybe you should consider reformatting your question so the rules are first and in those rules the image dimensions comes as the first rule. 
People are lazy and only read the first couple of lines and keep on reading only when it interests them ;)

Comment: @Stormenet: We had the same problem when the rules were first. Some people just don't read the rules...

Answer (score 16):

### At Camp

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/4669707)

Comment: That's beautiful. It's the trail leading us through the snow and into the scene that makes it.

Comment: Thank you @Mark.

Answer (score 15):

## Sharp look-out

[image]

An image of one of multiple booths that shelter the dam flow control machinery of a hydroelectricity power plant through the river Rhine.

They always seemd to me like guards looking out for problems - like a Meerkat - in their case maybe for the big wave?

larger versions on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/michelpfirter/5833579891/) or [500px](http://www.500px.com/photo/947360)

Comment: I like this, and in fact have upvoted, but it isn't quite straight, and that bothers me. With a completely symmetric shot like this, straightness is important. It is more obvious upon enlarging.

Comment: @BBischof, absolutely. Unfortunately I noticed the flaw also while scaling down for this submission. So I fixed the straightness in post for the image here. But since I had bad experiences with updating an image on flickr (comments, views, links removed) the larger versions still have that flaw of not proper straightness. Thank you for your comment and of course for upvoting :-)

Comment: I like the photo. Looks like an owl to me.

Comment: @Vian Esterhuizen: thank you, yeah could be an owl too :)

Answer (score 8):

///
[image: ///]

(battle of the oranges!)

Comment: Nice point of view.

Answer (score 7):

### **This is my Mango!**

[image]

[in big here](http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/indonesia-2011/photos/#!169919850068)

Comment: I like this photo but I didn't know you could eat a mango with the skin on

Comment: @flur and neither without washing the hands before (see nails) :-)

Comment: I didn't even notice that :P (lol @ flur)

Answer (score 6):

## 2 To GO!

[image: Purple Beauty]

Larger one [here](http://500px.com/photo/4549979)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

iN deep thoughts

Answer (score 3):

## Straight from the horse's mouth

[image: Straight from the horse's mouth]

Lensbaby Composer, Double Glass, f/5.6

[Larger](http://nagi.ee/photos/a4imrel/14944811/in-set/14373/)

Answer (score 3):

### Orange Bubbles

[image]

Comment: Awesome color. Love the subtle texture, too :)

Comment: Thanks, it is melted red boiled sweets

Comment: Very nice. Do you have a larger version?

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/blueboxes/6831504647/

Answer (score 1):

### I can walk in Snow

[image: I can walk in Snow]

---

[Larger](https://500px.com/photo/4765293)

Comment: "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide"