# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 13, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 13 February** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Feb 12th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/weekly-featured-image-feb-6-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 25):

### To The Jubilee Line

[image: To The Jubilee Line]

This was taken at London Bridge train station. You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6816081817/).

Comment: Oooooohhhh... Love it!

Comment: Great capture & colours! Like your flickr photos as well. Looks like you are having a lot of fun with this lens. (f2.8 wow, fast for a fisheye)

Comment: Dude, I'm beginning to think you're a homeless guy haunting the tube with a DSLR... ;)

Comment: I do try to get above ground now and again to get some sunlight!

Answer (score 16):

### [missing...](http://flic.kr/p/bp3bEZ)

[image]

[Original in Flickr](http://flic.kr/p/bp3bEZ)

Comment: Cool! Added as favorite in my flickr :)

Comment: thanks, is my favorite too... ;)

Comment: Oooh, I love this! So poignant.

Answer (score 15):

### Hermit the Crab

[image: Hermit the Crab]

Big can be found [here](http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/indonesia-2011/photos/#!169920108620)

Comment: Nice details. :)

Comment: Really nice details :) I like http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/indonesia-2011/photos/#!169918521800 this one as well

Comment: thank you guys :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Location: Harihareshwar, India]

Location: Harihareshwar, India

You can see the original on my website: http://nimishdalal.me/?attachment_id=181

Comment: Hi @Nimish - "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide" which is landscape orientation