# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 20, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 20 February** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Feb 19th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1937/weekly-featured-image-feb-13-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Note that the "submit your photo" link on the main page still goes to last week's contest...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Fixed.

Answer (score 21):

**Cracking**

[image]

Comment: Cracking shot! Out of interest, where was it taken?

Comment: Looks like Scarborough in January

Comment: Thanks guys! Taken last week minutes after sunrise in Thunder Bay, Ontario, Canada. This is the Brule Bay on Lake Superior (Fort William First Nations reserve) and it's the Sleeping Giant formation on the horizon. I actually took 2 very similar images and one is [portrait orientation](http://500px.com/photo/4863391) which I prefer but it would not look good cropped.

Comment: Very nice in portrait. What's it like in colour, out of interest?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - Not bad, a lot more cheerful. I prefer the B&W. I don't often come across something that's suitable for B&W and I thought this worked pretty well with the snow ice texture, etc. This is a 3 exposure HDR B&W BTW. I don't have the colour version on the web. I like to post either one or the other. I can email it if you'd like.

Comment: Just curious, no need to trouble yourself.

Comment: That's stunning in portrait!

Comment: Thanks @mdresser.

Answer (score 9):

**The Girl On The Beach**

Not much to say, a photo with an analog camera 20 years ago, hope that you like it for the valentine day.

[image: girl on the beach]

relative with this questions: 
[Shooting on the beach: is it dangerous for my equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/shooting-on-the-beach-is-it-dangerous-for-my-equipment)  ,  [How to use a tripod on the beach without damaging it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20202/how-to-use-a-tripod-on-the-beach-without-damaging-it)

by the way, still have this camera, is full metal old 35mm camera with a metal shutter/cutain ! Survive the beach :)

Comment: Do you still have the girl too? :)

Comment: I was about to say I like the old film look and then I saw it IS an old photo. I really like it

Answer (score 8):

### Hermit the Crab

[image: Hermit the Crab]

Big can be found [here](http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/indonesia-2011/photos/#!169920108620)

Comment: Well, I normally withhold my vote till the end in case a tie needs to be broken, but I really like this photo, so I'm voting now. :) Here's to hoping you win this week around!

Comment: @jrista thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Dizzy**

[image: Dizzy]

Larger (pre-crop) version [here](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7178/6872136167_1a505732c2_b.jpg).

Comment: Is that a photo?

Comment: Yes... It's a photo of a spinning hypno wheel at the @Bristol Science museum... it's shot with 1 second exposure

Comment: why the odd crop?

Comment: I like the crop!

Comment: @rfusca: I think circles lend themselves to a square crop.  As to why that section of the picture, it is difficult to quantify but I guess I find that section of the spiral more inviting.

Comment: Does this qualify as landscape orientation?

Comment: @Martha: It should do.  The top is the long side, however as it is a square it just so happens to also be the short side.

Comment: we'll let it slide ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Patagonian View

The awesome landscape photo that described my entire trip to Patagonia. Took at El Calafate.

[image: Patagonia View]

Larger image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nathanpc/6854217081/)

Answer (score 4):

On a lazy Sunday afternoon!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Redmond Public Library at Night**

[image: Redmond Public Library at Night]

This was taken back in 2002 or so on one of my many night time photography sessions in the Seattle area.  The Redmond Public Library was close to my work and has interesting lighting and architecture.

Comment: That's a great shot!

Answer (score 3):

**The Seine, Paris**

[image: The Seine River, Paris]

Answer (score 3):

**Dazed**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Stalking The Elusive [*Western Red Sunset*](https://plus.google.com/photos/111471664614886058938/albums/5694235458707286625/5694248530607544434?banner=pwa)

The clouds in afternoon sky gave hope of great sunset pictures that evening. But like timid children fleeing a schoolyard bully the clouds retreated with the sun until, at sundown, they were but a thin line on the western horizon. Only my largest lens had any chance of capturing images full of rich sunset colors and shapes. It didn't happen.  Though they were not very tall, the clouds proved to be deep and the sun was barely able to punch through. I doubt any of the photos will make my portfolio.

Despite the lack of magazine-quality pictures the session was a success. I had the privilege of watching a sunset while looking for slices of beauty to carve out of it. Sunrises and sunsets remind me the earth is spinning "under" the sun and I contemplate the universe and my place in it. The photos taken are raw material for improvement. Shooting the sunset was somehow both invigorating and relaxing.

[image: Camera on tripod]