# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 27, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 27 February** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Feb 26th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1937/weekly-featured-image-feb-20-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: The submit photo link is still pointing at last weeks question (1950) instead of this one (1977)

Comment: Two weeks from now, starting March 5th, it will be a theme week.  The theme will be 'Earth" - one of the 4 'classical elements'.  Prepare and show how creative you can be! http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/picture-of-the-week-theme-ideas

Comment: @rfusca Shouldn't this be a separate announcement?

Comment: @Anisha: I've made an official [announcement thread](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/picture-of-the-week-theme-elements-earth-for-week-of-march-5-12).

Comment: @jrista Thanks, I didn't notice it before posting here.

Answer (score 17):

### Shoot First, Sightsee Later

[image: ShootFirst]

This was taken in Bruges, Belgium on a very cold February afternoon. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6863077251/).

Comment: Thats a trippy picture.

Comment: Love this photo. +1  The linked image seems a bit darker or more "contrasty". I like it better. Perhaps sizing down the photo lessened the contrast?

Comment: I somehow missed the voting for this week, but I have to say I'm glad this particular image won. I know there's nothing concrete in the image that should be leading me this way, but I can't help being reminded of M.C. Escher's *Relativity* and *Convex and Concave*. Orientation is almost a matter of choice.

Comment: Thanks Stan, I appreciate the feedback :-)

Answer (score 12):

**Cleared for Landing**

[image: bee]

I can't sit and wait for a bee to land on a particular flower, so I chase them around the garden and get hundreds of blurry shots.  Got lucky with this one, he hovered long enough for me to focus and get a nice composition to boot.  Check out the pollen on his little feet!

Comment: nice shot, what lens did you use?

Comment: 105mm f/2.8 VR Micro

Comment: This should have won. Amazing photo.

Comment: Thank you!  I had an image featured a few weeks back, so quite happy to come second.

Answer (score 9):

**#### Reflection**

[image: Reflection]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6009904378/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 7):

## Golden Wave

[image: Golden Wave]

[Flickr version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/6778455848/in/photostream)

Answer (score 3):

**Effet Papillon**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Sunrise

Late in the week I know, but freshly peeled from the sky this morning.

[image]