# Weekly Featured Image: March 5, '12

Tags: discussion

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 5 March** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on March 4th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

This week, there is no particular [theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) for the contest. All photos which would be appropriate for the banner are welcome.

### **Next week the theme is EARTH**.

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/weekly-featured-image-feb-27-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Some great photos this week!

Answer (score 16):

## Golden Coast

[image: Golden Coast]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/6775959136/in/photostream)

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful (esp. the larger version).

Comment: Thanks @ysap! It helps to have such a photogenic subject. :)

Comment: +1 a great photo!

Answer (score 13):

**The Creek**

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/5239735)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Female Northern Cardinal]

Female Northern Cardinal; larger on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/danwolfgang/5435079020/in/photostream).

Comment: Lovely! Awesome colours, gorgeous bokeh. Well done! +1

Answer (score 9):

### [smoke...](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/6933535027/in/photostream)

[image: smoke]

[Original in Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/6933535027/in/photostream)

Answer (score 7):

[image: South Crater]

South Crater, Tongariro National Park, New Zealand

Comment: nice photo!... the red color in the crater is interesting...

Comment: yes, that will be iron in the volcanic rock

Answer (score 1):

## Country Living

[image: Ringneck Pheasant]

I photographed this Ringneck Pheasant through my laundry room window.  Larger version [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/111471664614886058938/2011Wildlife02#5681225841576376994).

Answer (score 0):

Wet flower

[image: Wet flower]

Large version - [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/6925244691/in/photostream/lightbox/)