# Weekly Featured Image: Mar 12, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 12 March** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on March 11th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

### **THIS WEEK's theme is EARTH**

This theme is the first of a four-week series. The NEXT FOUR WEEKS will conform to the theme below. Each week will be for a different element: Earth, Air, Water, Fire. The idea is to depict the ancient "Classical Elements", often involved in magic, fundamental to the workings and creation of the universe. Opposing and complementary.

This week's theme is about the **Classical Element of EARTH**. All photos must involve this primordial element in some way or another. Keep in mind, a normal picture of a landscape probably won't quite do it, you'll need to get more creative than that. ;)

[See full details about the theme here.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/picture-of-the-week-theme-classical-elements-earth-for-week-of-march-5-12)

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/weekly-featured-image-march-5-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Nice work getting the closing timezone right (EDT).

Answer (score 11):

[image: Dunes, Death Valley NP]

[Dunes, Death Valley National Park](http://www.flickr.com/photos/coneslayer/2450766738/in/set-72157604959344927/lightbox/)

Comment: Wow, very impressive image.

Comment: The hard part is walking out far enough that there are no footprints!

Comment: Lovely! Like the shadow in the middle ground. Is that caused by another dune casting the shadow?

Comment: @Jakub, I don't remember the geometry for sure (it was taken 8 years ago), but I think the shadow is just the shadow of the dune in the picture. I don't think the other dunes were so much taller or close enough to cast a shadow over the top of this dune. I was out there waiting a while for a moment like this, just as the dune transitions from light to shadow at sunset.

Answer (score 7):

Volcanic

[image: Earth]

Tongariro National Park, NZ.  The lakes are emerald color from dissolved minerals.

Comment: I am quite glad I can see some little people in the bottom left. I always miss that in my shots!

Comment: I try to NOT get people in my shots, but in this case it was unavoidable, and I think it adds scale to the picture, probably better for it even though I prefer to keep it pristine :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I think it's sort of funny that I post a photo of the effects of water erosion in the "earth" theme, but here it is: a rock. I've no clue what type of rock it is -- must be sedimentary based on the wear, I guess. Details of the canoe trip I shot this on, along with a bigger version at [Troop 29’s Visit to the Allagash Wilderness Waterway](http://danandsherree.com/2009/07/30/troop-29s-visit-to-the-allagash-wilderness-waterway.php).

Comment: Ah, I like the "opposites" concept captured here. The power of water over earth. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Bodega Bay (Santa Rosa, CA)]

Large version: [Bodega Bay (Santa Rosa, CA)](http://goo.gl/AZDqj)

Comment: You need you scale it down to the required dimensions in the contest rules.

Comment: Done! I updated img tag in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## A glimpse to the inner side

[image: A glimpse to the inner side]

A curve on road TF-24 (Parque Nacional del Teide, Tenerife) reveals the layers that have taken thousands of years to form, zealously intruded by humans and trees.

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/66518020@N08/6809874220/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: You just happened to be on the canary islands this past week to shoot some earth shots?! Very cool!

Comment: @dpollitt: When you get to 14k rep, the StackExchange travel subsidy kicks in. You're almost there!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Boulders next to the beach.

[Larger Version](https://picasaweb.google.com/115868136765822134407/March52012#5716452196427131570)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Roxborough]

Grabbed this shot while on a trip to Roxborough State Park near Denver. I visited here after a recommendation from [@jrista](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14/2011/6/13/21-24), so I figured this was a good place to put one of the images I took :)

Comment: Thanks @jrista!

Comment: Nice. Interesting formations.

Answer (score 1):

Tamed

[image: Tamed]

[Bigger (pre-crop)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74385744@N08/6822998828/)

Comment: Hello forsvarir. I'm not sure if you noticed that this week was a theme week or not. If you did, could you explain how this conforms to the theme rules?

Comment: @jrista: It depicts the 'Taming' of earth into forced regularity to form one of the foundations for modern living, a brick.  I'm happy to take down-votes don't believe it fits into the theme.

Comment: Nope, thanks for the explanation. Rather clever, if you ask me. ;) I think the real meaning of the contest was misunderstood in general, but thats nothing against you personally.

Comment: I caught the intention as soon as I saw the title.