# Weekly Featured Image: Mar 19, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 19 March** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on March 18th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

### **THIS WEEK's theme is AIR**

This theme is the second of a four-week series. The NEXT THREE WEEKS will conform to the theme below. Each week will be for a different element: Earth, Air, Water, Fire. The idea is to depict the ancient "Classical Elements", often involved in magic, fundamental to the workings and creation of the universe. Opposing and complementary.

This week's theme is about the **Classical Element of AIR**. All photos must involve this whimsical element in some way or another. We encourage you to show you creative side here - show us the invisible in a photograph.

[See full details about the theme here.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/picture-of-the-week-theme-classical-elements-air-for-week-of-march-12-12)

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/weekly-featured-image-mar-12-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: I thought we had a bunch of aviation experts, where are they?!

Comment: Pokes @jamwheel .

Answer (score 16):

**Air**

[image]

Comment: smoke == "polluted" air ;)

Comment: @Anisha don't take it so literally

Comment: That was supposed to be a joke! :mad:

Comment: @Anisha - Lol, sorry then.  Internet and the whole not-being-good-at-conveying-emotion-thing.

Comment: Larger Version? What settings did you use to get this shot?

Comment: @Treebranch - I'll put a larger version up tonight and I'll update a short "how it was done" I guess.

Comment: @Treebranch - I haven't had a chance to upload - if it wins, I'll do a blog post about smoke shots.

Comment: @rfusca worth a blog post even if you don't - stop making bread, and get writing :)

Answer (score 16):

### Smoke Signal

[image: Smoke trailing a formation of acrobatic jets]

The smoke trails of a formation of Thunderbird F-16 jets above the Andrew Air Force Base in Maryland, USA.

Heavily cropped version of [this photo](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Events/Andrews-AFB-Airshow-2011/17422799_t47ZSQ#!i=1325270493&k=VzcM56T). Post processing in Aperture was limited to straighten, crop, curves, desaturation and light sharpening.

Answer (score 6):

**Windy Sunset**

[image]

It was a windy day on the beach with the sand drawing lines on the beach, as I was walking behind a dune on my way back to the house I saw the sun just between the dune grass, as I was taking the photo a gust blew by.

[Larger Version here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ksmit/6829204174/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 5):

### Sky

[image: Sky]

Taken from a gravel road on an old Midwestern farm.

[Large Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/77952351@N06/6980334863/sizes/l/in/photostream/)

Answer (score 2):

**Schooling over the cloud**

[image]

I wouldn't mind going there at all ;) Taken at **Darjeeling**, West Bengal, India.

Larger version in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/6966060825/lightbox/).

Answer (score 1):

**Bird's eye view**

[image]

Gannet soaring over the beach.  Taken from a cliff near a nesting site.

Answer (score 1):

### Blue Heaven

[image: Blue Heaven]

After a short rain we got we got a really fresh air and this beautiful blue color on the sky (Belitung, Indonesia Nov. 2011). [Large Version here](http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/indonesia-2011/photos/#!169923660469)

Answer (score 1):

Uplifting

[image: Uplifting]

[Bigger (precrop)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74385744@N08/6831378238/)

Comment: Yeah, I’m a work in progress.  Historically I’ve not had that much time for post-processing so don’t really know my way round the software that well (so it takes longer... have less time... etc...).  I’m having some difficulty cropping to the right size (as stupid as that sounds).  I imagine there’s also a good chance that the original focus was slightly off. I may re-crop less aggressively to see if it helps.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: FWIW, I like the uncropped shot better!

Comment: Just crop it how you want it, then resize the whole thing so that height is 210.  Then if the width exceeds the maximum (375?) you may have to crop the ends off.

Comment: @MikeW: I set-up a 210x375 custom crop in picasa, however when resizing the crop it only seems to let you resize along the x-axis, maintaining the ratio with the y-axis... however it seems to randomly set the y to between 209 + 211... and I'm not sure why... bit odd really...

Comment: But it looks like when you use that custom crop, it's going to cut a small 210x375 chunk out of your much larger original image, if I understand correctly.  So I'm thinking resize it down to a small size in the neighborhood of 210x3xx and then crop.

Comment: @DanWolfgang: Thanks, I like the uncropped version better as well, partly because that's the way I originally frammed it and partly because looking at crops of the picture it's clear that mattdm is right about the picture being slightly blurred (probably a combination of slightly missed focus and moving balloons).  All stuff to think about next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Life

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Morning Fog

[image]

Some birds in flight as the sun tries to fight through the thick morning fog.

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jbranchaud/6991294751/in/set-72157629147907676/)

Comment: there's only a day left in this weeks competition - you may want to save your entry for another week, your choice though.

Comment: I don't expect to win. I was able to get this shot just the other morning and thought it was fitting, so I posted it. I hope everyone enjoys it!

Answer (score 0):

## Clear Morning

[image]
The sky is peeking through a gap in the trees atop the good ol' Smoky Mountains.

Comment: You need to resize your image... Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide